# Run batch file with parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I would like to run a batch file with some extra character at the end.
If I write it directly to cmd it is working, like change directory to `"c:\Users\Public\Uploader\"` and write the following: `start.bat "cmd:file.import c:\Users\tom\Desktop\a.xml"`

I do not know how to write it in VBScript, because the following script is not working:

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.CurrentDirectory="C:\Users\Public\Uploader\"
WshShell.Run "start.bat" & "cmd:file.import C:\Users\tom\Desktop\a.xml"
```

The `a.xml` should dynamically change based on the last modified file in the folder.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: [What have you tried so far that isn't working](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Also, there's no space between your start.bat and its parameters.

Comment: You have it right - and good spot by @ManoDestra. I find it's easier to troubleshoot and build correct commands by uing strings to build the command and echo it before you run it. Sometimes seeing it in front of your eyes makes it easy to spot the missing spaces or quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to duplicate what you're doing in the command prompt, you need to add a space between the batch file name and its arguments. You also need to add the quotes.

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.CurrentDirectory="C:\Users\Public\Uploader\"
WshShell.Run "start.bat " & chr(34) & "cmd:file.import C:\Users\tom\Desktop\a.xml" & chr(34)
```